# Swift: how to disable user interaction while touch action is being carried out?

Tags: swift

I'm working with sprite kit and if the user touches the screen, the actions within

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    }
}
```

are carried out. While they're  being carried out, however, the user can still tap the screen and the app tries to run the actions again.

How do I disable touch interaction/the actions within the touch func while the actions are running?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to get the view from the touch object and then dissable the user interaction on it.

```
touch.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: I do not understand why, but this solution not work for me. Any of all solutions proposed here, work for me. I do not understand the reason.

Answer (score 43):

To disable user interaction app-wide, use:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
```

(as of Swift 5 this is deprecated)

Comment: This is deprecated after iOS 13

Comment: How to fix this globally (navigation bar, everything, etc.) in a most simple way? Is `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled` (but this does not disable navigation bar interaction) the only solution? Or can you do this on `keyWindow` ?

Comment: @sabiland didn't have this use case for some time now, but one hacky solution I can think of is putting a view on top of the whole screen, which captures all touch events without passing them to the views below

Comment: Is it ok to do `isUserInteractionEnabled` on `keyWindow` ? I tried it and it WORKS, but every Tap on UI throws some warnings in console log.

Comment: @sabiland I'd assume it's okay, but can't tell you for sure. Seems you get a warning because the touch didn't get passed even through the window itself, as some internal sanity check? If you're not comfortable with the appearing message, maybe implement the view on top of the whole app as mentioned above - that seems more predictable to me.

Comment: @sabiland alternatively you can disable user interaction for the view and the navigation bar buttons directly (same for tab bar and so on)

Answer (score 38):

In **Swift 3.0** is:

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Xcode 9.4.1 SDK 11.4  Swift 4.1 :  still the same as above self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled  = false

Comment: Still same on Swift 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use boolean class variable to stop interaction while method is performing, and after that you can just change value of boolean, at the end of the method.

Use `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` at the end of the first method, then change value of boolean and then use another method with start line `UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()`.

Answer (score 2):

For SwiftUI, expanding on @mojtaba-hosseini answer. 
You wanna make sure you fill your view with some color, except Clear color (you can always change opacity). I've also added blur to hide elements. Here's what worked for me:

**SwiftUI:**

```
ZStack{
    SomeView().blur(radius: 12)
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.white.opacity(0))
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
}
```

Another way to disable user interactions like scroll or button taps, but attach an action to user taps (for example a message to users that this feature is coming or behind a paywall):

**SwiftUI:**

```
VStack{
    SomeView().blur(radius: 12)
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture {
    print("No access!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### - SwiftUI

```
SomeView()
.allowsHitTesting(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

just go to storyboard and uncheck this option in any object which u want to disable the interaction of the user 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a Buttons user's interaction, just do this when the screen loads.

```
self.btnname.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

If you want to disable the user interaction as a view, it will be same just remove the button name and add the view's name.

If for some reasons, you want to enable interaction, just change "false" to "true".